# TinyMCE state frozen

Tags: reactjs, tinymce

When I load a users data into a tinymce editor, it will set the data within the editor to the current state value. However, its not allowing me to change this data. When I attempt to type anything into the editor, it will force the state back to what it was originally.

```
                                                                <Editor
                                                                apiKey=key
                                                                initialValue={this.state.tinymcebody}
                                                                init={{
                                                                    height: 500,
                                                                    menubar: false,
                                                                    color_cols: 8,
                                                                    color_rows: 5
                                                                }}
                                                                onChange={this.handleEditorChange}
```

This is my editorChange function

```
handleEditorChange(e) {
    this.setState({
        tinymcebody: e.target.getContent()
    });
}
```

My problem is that the data refuses to update after being set to the initial state, I tried changing initialValue to value, I tried setting both initialValue and value, none of it works. I was wondering if theres some data pipelining issue, or if anyone knows the cause of this.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a `value` prop in `Editor`, just add:

```
<Editor
   ...
   value={this.state.tinymcebody}
   ...
/>
```

This forces the editor to be "controlled" (that is foces `value` as content)